# Получение данных из MySQL c помощью PHP и React

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, axios

Здравствуйте хочу вытащить из базы MySQL все данные, но возвращяет только первую строку. Хочу отметить что такой код работает нормально, на localhost. Как я могу узнать в чем причина ошибки

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase //
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

API.js

```
export const getPictures = createAsyncThunk(
   'get/pic',
   async() => {
      const files = await axios.get(LINKS.GETPICTURE)
      .then((r) => {
         return r.data
      }).catch((err) => {
         console.log(err)
      })
      return files
   }
)
```

slice

```
const initialState:LoginSliceState = {
   allPics: []
}

const picSlice = createSlice({
   name: 'pic',
   initialState,
   reducers: {
   },
   extraReducers(builder) {
      builder.addCase(getPictures.fulfilled, (state: any, action) => {
         state.allPics = action.payload
      })
   }
})
```

gallery.js

```
 const {allPics} = useSelector(state => state.pics);
 const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(getPictures());
  }, [])

{allPics && allPics.map(elem =>
    (<img key={elem.id} image={elem.pic_name}/>)
)}
```

Php

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'name');
if(!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pictures";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    print_r($row);
}
```

[image: MySQL]

результат тот же, получаю только первый
Array ( [id] => 4 [pic_name] => images/gallery/51385-1d4b1280-9d7b-4459-993a-ce44c8ffbb40.jpg)
print_r($result) mysqli_result Object ([num_rows] => 8)

Comment: Ну так смысл функции mysqli_fetch_array именно в том, чтобы вернуть ровно одну строку, почему бы не использовать mysqli_fetch_all какой-нибудь

Comment: @andreymal Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()

Comment: Если у вас настолько старая версия php, то, согласно документации, включите расширение mysqlnd

Comment: @andreymal Версия  7.4.30, нужно установить mysqlnd?

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, проблему решил в базе поменяв кодировку на utf8_general_ci